# Small aircraft launchers

Tags: orbit, satellite-constellation

I have read that Stratolaunch carrier from ALTAIR project has a 117 m wingspan, it will weight in at over 540,000 kg including the fully fueled launch vehicle and will require a runway at least 3,700 m long. Also, it will be able to carry over 230,000 kg of payload...

White Knight Two is also a huge vehicle and there are many others.

Why are all this huge?

Wouldn't it be a good idea to use many small jets or small planes instead?

Comment: Consider: Why do we ever use any large rockets at all?

Comment: Great idea! In fact, it's been done already. http://www.designation-systems.net/dusrm/m-135.html

Comment: @NathanTuggy to be able to bring large payloads but, what if you just want to launch a 5 kg satellite? Would there be any regulatory problem in obtaining a launching license from FAA for example?
The fact that no companies have done it is extrange...

Comment: @OrganicMarble when I said "jets", I was considering small private jets (0,5 M dollars - 1 M dollars) not military jets ($30M). Actually, most recently SALVO project wanted to use an F-15 too

Comment: @user3894819 if you find a small private jet you can buy for 0,5 M dollars please private message me immediately so I can buy it. https://www.bankrate.com/loans/how-much-does-a-private-jet-cost/

Comment: Assembling many small pieces of payload in orbit would be difficult. Launching a larger single piece payload would save mass.

Comment: @OrganicMarble a Learjet from the 90s would cost about 500k

Comment: @Uwe you are right, assembling would be dificult but what if you just want to launch small payload?

Answer (score 2):

The carrier aircraft you highlight are large so they can carry large enough rockets to lift large enough payloads to satisfy the market segments their companies are aiming for. Smaller aircraft could only loft smaller rockets, limiting the final payload size to much smaller payloads.

Any launch vehicle, whether it's a traditional ground launched rocket or an air-launched one, generally starts with a payload target and then some basic physics principles will apply and dictate the size of the preceding stages in order to deliver that payload.

Comment: Two additional points: (1) even starting from an aerial launch it takes a lot of rocket fuel to get a relatively small satellite into orbit so a small rocket can only launch a tiny satellite (2) assembling stuff in orbit is possible, but reallty hard, so launching a big satellite in pieces is almost never economic

Comment: "to satisfy the market segments their companies are aiming for". Yes but with the aim to operate in the microsatellite sector, smaller aircraft carriers would exploit better the idea of "launch-in-demand"... I was wondering if there would be any legal or regulatory problem in launching it from small aircrafts instead of a huge and expensive one, as all the companies are doing

Comment: Also, to couple the rocket to the aircraft, I do not think it would be extremely difficult. What do you think?

Comment: If launching rockets from airplanes would be easy, by the way, I'd be more afraid of North Korea's arsenal of airplanes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know that any kid bored in his home could not build a competitive rocket... Large team are studying it during years

Comment: you asked whether it *would be extremely difficult*: obviously, yes.